# Managing file include different for different enviornments in gulp

Tags: gulp

I have AngularJs project which has entry and common file as `index.html`, in that file I have included various `js` and `css`. Now when I have to upload to production mode I want to change paths to minified versions of files. How to manage this automatically with gulp?

It is not possible for me to generate `index.html` file for production, then revert it again for development mode everytime. I have tried `gulp-inject` `gulp-replace`. All works but for that I have to revert again for production mode.

Comment: share some code please?

Comment: Why revert it again?? create a raw `index.html` file and create both `production mode` and `dev mode` from it. Why you want to work with one file??

Comment: But for that i have to add condition for production and development mode and angular js index.html not including files conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different variable in your `gulpfile.js`. One of them for `prod` and the other one for `dev`. The first variable contains paths of minified files And the second one contains paths of original files.

```
var dev = [
        'path-of-files.js',
        'path-of-files.js'
    ];

gulp.task('dev', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('path-of-raw-index');
    return target
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(devMode)))
        .pipe(concat('dev-index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target-path'));
});

gulp.task('prod', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('path-of-raw-index');
    return target
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(prodMode)))
        .pipe(concat('prod-index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target-path'));
});
```

And put these line of codes in `raw-index-file` where you want to inject

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- built js files will go here... -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

Comment: With this solution every time when want to move to production mode than execute this gulp fie which will replace and add prod files which is fine. But than when want to again start with development have to revert it and execute gulp with development. I want solution so that i can avoid this revert again and again.

Comment: A solution which you have both files at the same time and not running `gulp` command every time?? @Pinal